# Is there a way to use a different quote style for quoting the question body?

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

Very often, I find the need to use different quote styles in my answers. Typically, I want to be able to quote the question but also external documents.

For example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171935/829571), I would have liked to be able to format the first 2 quotes (quoting the OP) differently from the last one (quoting official documentation).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is only the bog standard quote.

I prefix my quotes with some context. For example, you said:

> I would have liked to be able to format the first 2 quotes

and then I can explain some more and quote again:

> Very often, I find the need to use different quote styles in my answers.

I don't agree, myself. Quotes never stand on their own; they need context. Giving them different styles would not help provide that context.

Comment: "Giving them different styles would not help provide that context." Here I'm quoting you without formatting and it works too. It's just less readable...

Comment: @assylias Shading one of those quotes in a different color may indicate that they are somehow different, but how useful is that? The surrounding text will provide that context whether the quotes are the same color or different. I despise HTML e-mail but people want to use it for the same reasons - using color to provide emphasis or different meaning when actual words are much better at doing that.